# Rewrite rules in Wordpress from url parameter and show custom content

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite urls in Wordpress in the following way:

Requested urls:

http://example.com/page

http://example.com/page/?lang=en-GB

http://example.com/page/?lang=en-WLS

http://example.com/page/?lang=en-SCT

Rewritten to:

http://example.com/page

http://example.com/nireland/page/

http://example.com/wales/page/

http://example.com/scotland/page/

I then ideally need to access which country has been requested so that I can display the appropriate content for that country.

Each of these urls should point to the same page.  Each page has page meta for the different country content.

This is my code so far, but I am not sure how to proceed

```
function language_rewrite()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '/([^/]+)?$/i',
        'index.php?lang=matches[1]',
        'top'
    );

    add_rewrite_tag('%lang%','([^/]*)');
}
add_action('init', 'language_rewrite');

function vars($vars)
{
    $vars[] = 'lang';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'vars');
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks, G.

**EDIT:**

```
add_rewrite_rule('^scotland/?([^/]*)', 'index.php?lang=en-SCT&pagename=$matches[1]', 'top');
add_rewrite_tag('%lang%','([^/]*)');
```

**EDIT2:**

```
add_rewrite_rule('^scotland/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)', 'index.php?lang=en-SCT&pagename=$matches[1]/$matches[2]/$matches[3]/$matches[4]/$matches[5]', 'top');
```

Comment: if you are using the rewrite rules, the requested urls would actually be what the user enters as the uri, rather than changing the url.  so `http://example.com/nireland/page/` would be typed in and could be matched to `http://example.com/page/?lang=en-GB` but you need to identify the uri by post id or post name

Comment: Thanks very much @David, I have re-jigged my add_rewrite_rule declaration and its works perfectly with urls in this format: http://example.com/scotland/page/ but I also need it to work for pages with more uri segmenets i.e http://example.com/scotland/section/sub-section/page/ I essentially want $matches[1] in my edited code to contain the rest of the url after /scotland/.  Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: it will might get messy, you will be basically overwriting the entire rewrite class for wp, so you will need you matches to check each taxonomy etc....have you considered seperate wp installations for each country (you can connect to the same db) that will solve the scotland issue while allowing you to have section/subsection (taxonomy?) without a lot of coding.

Comment: Thanks again David. That's not an option with this project unfortunately. And yes if I had to declare each section, sub-section, subsub-section etc (the entire site is hierarchical) it would very quickly get out of control. I have opted for the code in my EDIT2 for now - I know its not very pretty but it works for now, as in the future we are going to be removing the inbetween uri segments hopefully. Cheers :)